# Getting more summaries on object_detection/eval.py (the same as in train.py)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I'm using the [new tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) on my own data. It works very well, but I'm a bit disappointed that some statistics shown in Tensorboard are only there for the training set, not the eval, and inversely. For instance, I think it would be great to get the `global_step/sec` and the losses during evaluation, and also the `Precision` and `Performance` metrics for the training step (without evaluating manually on it).

Is there any simple way to do that ?

I'm training and testing with the scripts provided by the API, with pretty standard configuration files, with both *SSD* and *Faster-RCNN*:

```
python tensorflow_models_dir/object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=../models/SSD_v1/config_v1.config --train_dir=../models/SSD_v1/train
python tensorflow_models_dir/object_detection/eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=../models/SSD_v1/config_v1.config --checkpoint_dir=../models/SSD_v1/train --eval_dir=../models/SSD_v1/eval
```

So far I've tried adding the summaries from [`trainer.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/trainer.py) to the `tensor_dict` in [`evaluator.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/evaluator.py), but it failed at runtime. To do this, I've added the following lines to `_extract_prediction_tensors` in `evaluator.py`:

```
    # Gather initial summaries.
    summaries = set(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES))
    global_summaries = set([])


    # Add summaries.
    for model_var in slim.get_model_variables():
      global_summaries.add(tf.summary.histogram(model_var.op.name, model_var))
    for loss_tensor in tf.losses.get_losses():
      global_summaries.add(tf.summary.scalar(loss_tensor.op.name, loss_tensor))
    # global_summaries.add(
    #     tf.summary.scalar('TotalLoss', tf.losses.get_total_loss()))  # Crashes

    # Add the summaries from the first clone. These contain the summaries
    # created by model_fn and either optimize_clones() or _gather_clone_loss().
    summaries |= set(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES))
    summaries |= global_summaries

    # Merge all summaries together.
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge(list(summaries), name='summary_op')
    tensor_dict['summary_op'] = summary_op
```

Comment: It would help if you could share some code.

Comment: @Nicolas I've added some. I'm basically using the code in object_detection, modified a bit for python3, and the piece of code I've added above. I don't really know what to add, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What error is thrown when the code fails at runtime?